# How can I click multiple buttons by dragging in QtGui?

Tags: qt, python-3.x, button, pyqt, qtgui

I have a program that creates a grid of buttons using PyQt (all QPushButtons in a QGridLayout), like this:
[image: grid]

I was wondering how I can drag my mouse while holding mouse1 down to run each button's function for each one that the mouse is dragged over. Right now, when dragging and holding, only the button the click was started on is triggered, and no other buttons can be selected until mouse release. Is there a function that just runs it on press or release, or unselects the button after the function is ran?

For reference, my code for the currently selected button is as follows:

```
self.button.pressed.connect(lambda: self.click_func(self_global, x, y,
                                                    btn_id))
```

The function isn't important, and would just take up more room here, but I hope you get the point.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible with a stock button, but you could easily implement your own button which has this functionality, by using `setMouseTracking(true)` and overloading the `enterEvent()`

Comment: ddriver, how could I create my own button? I've really only used the QPushButton, I didn't even know you could make your own. An example of what you mean by the enterEvent() would be great too, I can't find much on the internet.

Comment: dunno how to do it from python, or whether it is even possible, but from C++ you can simply extend a widget or an abstract button, btw the mouse tracking and enter event should be present in the button as well, since it inherits QWidget.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `eventFilter`.  This allows you to send events to another `QObject` (usually the parent widget of the buttons) to decide what to do with them.

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def createButton(self):
        button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        button.setMouseTracking(True)
        button.installEventFilter(self)
        return button

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if isinstance(obj, QtGui.QPushButton):
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
                if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                    print 'Mouse Pressed Over Button'
        return False
```

Looking at your example, you may want to also consider using a [`QGraphicsView`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgraphicsview.html) and [`QGraphicsScene`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgraphicsscene.html).  They are good building blocks for creating truly custom widgets.  It's possible you may be able to hack QPushButtons to behave in a way they weren't intended, but for custom drawn widgets, `QGraphicsViews` are the way to go.

Comment: After modifying that code to fit my program, i get this error incessantly: AttributeError: 'PySide.QtCore.QEvent' object has no attribute 'buttons'

Comment: hmm, must not be a `QMouseEvent`.  Print out the event to see what type it is.  You can do an additional `if isinstance(event, QtGui.QMouseEvent)`